# JWT with Angular 8 and Springboot 2 : JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I found this [tutorial](https://github.com/senolatac/role-based-authorization) on github to implement the JWT with Angular 8 and springboot2. but while executing the same, I am facing exception given below.

```
io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0
```

on debugging further, that excpetion is coming from DefaultJwtParser.java, which is one of the class in JWT library

```
@Override
    public Jwt parse(String jwt) throws ExpiredJwtException, MalformedJwtException, SignatureException {

        Assert.hasText(jwt, "JWT String argument cannot be null or empty.");

        String base64UrlEncodedHeader = null;
        String base64UrlEncodedPayload = null;
        String base64UrlEncodedDigest = null;

        int delimiterCount = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);

        for (char c : jwt.toCharArray()) {

            if (c == SEPARATOR_CHAR) {

                CharSequence tokenSeq = Strings.clean(sb);
                String token = tokenSeq!=null?tokenSeq.toString():null;

                if (delimiterCount == 0) {
                    base64UrlEncodedHeader = token;
                } else if (delimiterCount == 1) {
                    base64UrlEncodedPayload = token;
                }

                delimiterCount++;
                sb.setLength(0);
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }

        if (delimiterCount != 2) {
            String msg = "JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: " + delimiterCount;
            throw new MalformedJwtException(msg);
        }
```

it means that the token should come in format of 'Bearer abc.def.ghi', but as per the tutorial it is coming like 'Bearer Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudA==' while I am doing the login.

Angular code

```
login(user: User): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(user ? {
      authorization:'Bearer '+ btoa(user.username + ':' + user.password)
    }:{});

    return this.http.get<any> (API_URL + "login", {headers:headers}).pipe(
      map(response => {
        console.log("map"+response);
        if(response) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
          this.currentUserSubject.next(response);
        }
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

Java code

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider
{
    @Value("${app.jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
    @Value("${app.jwt.token.prefix}")
    private String jwtTokenPrefix;
    @Value("${app.jwt.header.string}")
    private String jwtHeaderString;
    @Value("${app.jwt.expiration-in-ms}")
    private String jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication)
    {
        String authororities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining());
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(authentication.getName()).claim("roles", authororities)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtExpirationInMs))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if (token == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Claims claim = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        String username = claim.getSubject();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.stream(claim.get("roles").toString().split(","))
            .map(role -> role.startsWith("ROLE_") ? role : "ROLE_" + role)
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return username != null
                        ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities)
                        : null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if (token == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Claims claim = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        if (claim.getExpiration().before(new Date()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(jwtHeaderString);
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith(jwtTokenPrefix))
        {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I already tried removing the 'Bearer ' from authorization header, but things are not working.

Please let me know, if need any other details

Answer (score 0):

Jwt is defined as xxx.yyy.zzz where

- xxx is header information of you token like hash algorithm,
- yyy is the payload containing user information and
- zzz is a signature to verify the token. More on that here:

https://jwt.io/introduction/

You just sending `username:password` as base64 encoded ascii string. That would be the payload part yyy.

Spring expects xxx.yyy.zzz and throws an exception because without the header/signature, it's not a jwt.

So if you want to create a jwt in your front-end, you need to rewrite your code.

Btw: the token should never contain sensitive data like password.

**Update**

I would suggest this login workflow:

- User enters username / password in login form
- Your Angular Frontend does a POST request with the credentials, with username and the password as parameters. The password is encrypted, eg with the `bcrypt` algorithm. This algorithm is good for this use case, since it is quite slow and therefore harder to brute force. Your concern regarding browser network section is valid, but the `Authorization` header can be seen there as well in the `request header`, right above the query parameter part.
- The spring backend compares the credentials and returns a jwt token. The token can contain user information like username, roles or email address.
- The frontend stores the jwt eg in the localStorage of the browser. For every request, the token is added with the header as `Authorization: Bearer + ${token}`
- The backend can now validate the token on every request. No need to pass credentials every time.

This requires an auth server, which is currently not supported with spring security 5 (but this decision is under [reconsideration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6320#issuecomment-609978171) atm).

Alternatively you can user a third party provider like [aws cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito), which can handle user registration or login with social media accounts like google or facebook.

Or you can use something like the [google oauth api](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) for login. The user logs in with google, which returns a jwt, that you can use for backend authentication.

Or if you want to have user management under your control but don't want to implement the whole auth service, I can recommend [cas](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/index.html). This service can run as an independent application, which supports all kinds of authentication methods.

Comment: Then how exactly I can handle this situation, we cannot send it as post param otherwise once can see that in browser network section. Do you have any idea how can i deal with it on frontend side

Comment: The header can be read in the browser network section as well, so this doesn't solve your problem. I updated my answer to propose a login workflow.